# Can't v-bind:data on Object Tag Element inside template

Tags: javascript, pdf, vue.js

```
<object id="objectPDF" data="./static/relativity.pdf"></object>
```

I can't v-bind:data on Object Tag Element inside template.

Can't even do this.

```
<object id="objectPDF" data="{{ pdfUrl }}"></object>
```

Comment: Did u try v-bind:data="pdfUrl"

Comment: Yes, v-bind:data is actually undefined attribute value.

Comment: Can u prepare a small fiddle?

Comment: It's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Great so what was the problem?

Comment: I thought that v-bind:data="{{ pdfUrl }}" will worked,
v-bind:data="pdfUrl" worked!

I forgot that v-bind:<attribute>="value" doesn't requires {{ }} inside it. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer so the question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below =>

```
v-bind:data="pdfUrl"
```